# SkiaSharp encode to byteArray result is not the same as System.Drawing.Image.Save

Tags: c#, .net-standard, skiasharp

I am now trying to upgrade my project from .net framework 4.7.2 to .net Standard 2.0.
Since my project also need to run in Linux, for image processing (ex. Bitmap), I choose SkiaSharp which was also recommended in MSDN.

My question now is that when I trying to save bmp as different format (ex. Png or Jpeg) and get byte array, byte array result is different.

Since compatibility issue, is it possible that the output byte array can be the same?

**Code used Syste.Drawing**

```
....
var encoder = GetEncoder(imageFormat);
if (encoder == null)
{
    return Array.Empty<byte>();
}

var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

byte[] byteArray;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bmp.Save(stream, encoder, myEncoderParameters);
    byteArray = stream.ToArray();
}
....

public ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    try
    {
        var imageDecoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        return imageDecoders.FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == format.Guid);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Code used SkiaSharp**

```
public byte[] BmpToByteArrayByImageFormat(SKBitmap bmp, SKEncodedImageFormat imageFormat)
{
    try
    {
        var data = bmp.Encode(imageFormat, 50);

        return data.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Array.Empty<byte>();
    }
}
```

I have tried SKJpegEncoderOptions and SKPngEncoderOptions, but still cannot get the same result as using System.Drawing.Image.Save()

Comment: Different encoder & encoder settings will very likely produce different bitstreams if compression is used. This is perfectly normal and expected. This is because there are many different ways to compress data, and some encoders make different tradeoffs than others, even when using the same file format.

Comment: You should compare the decoded pixels instead of the encoded stream to determine if they are compatible.

Comment: I did compare the raw pixel array which is calculated from out byte array. If compare information for saving from Bitmap to Png, raw pixel info are the same, If compare information for saving from Bitmap to Jpeg, then raw pixel info are different.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The JPEG format uses a lossy compression algorithm, so converting a bitmap to a JPEG most likely won't result in identical pixels.